# How do I make one image appear in random locations on a canvas each time it is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a simple game in which the player must find an image somewhere on a canvas. However, I would like to make this single image appear at different locations on the canvas and then stay there until the canvas is loaded again. In other words, I do not want the image to just keep randomly appearing on the canvas after a certain time interval. Instead, I would like for the position of the image to be randomized every time the canvas is loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
function getpos(min, max) {
   return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
var c = document.getlementById('canvas');
var element = document.getlementById('element');
ymin = c.offsetLeft;
ymax = ymin + c.offsetWidth

xmin = c.offsetTop;
xmax = xmin + c.offsetHeight;


var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(element, getpos(xmin, xmax), getpos(ymin,ymax))
```

Comment: Thanks, if my image was called lspsay.gif, where would I place it in the code?

Comment: give it an id and but that id instead of 'element'

Comment: This won't work if the user wants to draw the image on the canvas. This assumes the user wants to move an img element over a canvas element

Comment: Yes, I would like to draw the image on the canvas. The only thing is, I set up a background for my canvas. Would that have an effect on what I'm trying to do?